# Expected number of maxima

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I have is algorithm, which takes an array as an argument, and returns its maximum value.

```
find_max(as) :=
    max = as[0]
    for i = 1 ... len(as) {
        if max < as[i] then max = as[i]
   }
    return max
```

My question is: given that the array is initially in a (uniformly) random permutation and that all its elements are distinct, what's the expected number of times the `max` variable is updated (ignoring the initial assignment).

For example, if `as = [1, 3, 2]`, then the number of updates to `max` would be 1 (when reading the value 3).

Comment: You should show some source code if you want your question to be relevant for stackoverflow. I don't understand which algorithm you are thinking of, but finding the max is of linear complexity

Comment: Actually there is just the condition on the algorithm that time takes when you change the variable and not in iteration.

Comment: Consider psuedo code: max = array[0] ; for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){     if(max<array[i]){max = array[i];}//only in this step the time counts      }

Comment: For 1,3,4, don't you change max variable twice? 1->3 and 3->4?

Comment: @notsogeek: please edit your question to add the code there

Comment: Are values from taken from some finite set? Like [1,M] interval? With replacemenet? Without? You cannot generate random number with uniform distribution without the bounds.

Comment: and M<N? M>N? M=N? Are we talking only about integers or also real values?

Comment: here doesn't matter because I am asking only for average number of possible steps(of change in value of the variable - max ).And the time complexity for comparison involved should be treated as zero.

Comment: I hope the question is clear ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Empirical Solution

A simulation of many different array sizes with multiple trials each can be performed and analyzed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define UPTO 10000
#define TRIALS 100

using namespace std;

int arr[UPTO];

int main(void){
  ofstream outfile ("tabsep.txt");
  for(int i = 1; i < UPTO; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int iter = 0; iter < TRIALS; iter++){
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        arr[j] = rand();
      }
      int max = arr[0];
      int times_changed = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if (arr[j] > max){
          max = arr[j];
          times_changed++;
        }
      }
      sum += times_changed;
    }
    int avg = sum/TRIALS;
    outfile << i << "\t" << avg << "\n";
    cout << "\r" << i;
  }
  outfile.close();
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

When I graphed these results, the complexity appeared to be logarithmic:

[image: Array size versus average number of times the max was changed]

---

I think it's safe to conclude that the time complexity is **O(log n)**.

---

### Theoretical solution:

- Assume that the numbers are in the range 0...n
- You have a tentative maximum m
- The next maximum will be a random number in the range m+1...n, which averages out to be (m+n)/2
- This means that each time you find a new maximum, you are dividing the range of possible maximums by 2
- Repeated division is equivalent to a logarithm
- Therefore the number of times a new maximum is found is **O(log n)**

Comment: Also if you can give me theoretical description for the algorithm as average steps being log(n)

Comment: I suppose that each time you find a number greater than the max, you cut down the amount of numbers that could be greater than the max by some factor. Therefore, it becomes repeated division AKA a logarithm.

Comment: @notsogeek I edited my answer to add the intuitive explanation.

Comment: I didn't get this ... shouldn't be the random number in range m...n be with probability 1/(n-m) for all the elements in next range.

Comment: Since the next maximum must be in the range m+1...n, it averages to be (m+n)/2. The main point is that a new maximum cuts the acceptable range for subsequent maximums by some factor.

Comment: But how do you say that next maximum will lie in the mid point of m+1...n ?

Comment: On average it will; I'm not saying it will happen all of the time. Average is what we are concerned with.

Comment: Upvoted, but your theoretical argument isn't rigorous since it assumes that you're taking the average case at each step. If the argument _were_ correct, then it would be possible to derive log_2(N) as the expectation (at least in the case where N was a power of 2).

Comment: Yes, I realize it wasn't rigorous, but its main point was to show that a new maximum cuts the number of possibilities of subsequent maximums by some factor. Because we are concerned with big O notation, the base of the logarithm doesn't really matter. I have to say though, your answer is incredibly impressive.

Answer (score 9):

Assume the original array contains the values 1, 2, ..., N.

Let X_i, i = 1..N be random variables that take the value 1 if i is, at some point during the algorithm, the maximum value.

Then the number of maximums the algorithm takes is the random variable: M = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_N.

The average is (by definition) E(M) = E(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_N). Using linearity of expectation, this is E(X_1) + E(X_2) + .. + E(X_N), which is prob(1 appears as a max) + prob(2 appears as a max) + ... + prob(N appears as a max) (since each X_i takes the value 0 or 1).

When does i appear as a maximum? It's when it appears first in the array amongst the i, i+1, i+2, ..., N. The probability of this is 1/(N-i+1) (since each of those numbers are equally likely to be first).

So... prob(i appears as a max) = 1/(N-i+1), and the overall expectation is 1/N + 1/(N-1) + ..+ 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1

This is Harmonic(N) which is approximated closely by ln(N) + emc where emc ~= 0.5772156649, the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Since in the problem you don't count the initial setting of the maximum to the first value as a step, the actual answer is Harmonic(N) - 1, or approximately ln(N) - 0.4227843351.

A quick check for some simple cases:

- N=1, only one permutation, and no maximum updates. Harmonic(1) - 1 = 0.
- N=2, permutations are [1, 2] and [2, 1]. The first updates the maximum once, the second zero times, so the average is 1/2. Harmonic(2) - 1 = 1/2.
- N=3, permutations are [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]. Maximum updates are 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 respectively. Average is (2+1+1+1)/6 = 5/6. Harmonic(3) - 1 = 1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6.

So the theoretical answer looks good!

Comment: This is the best answer. Probably you can give more explanation as of how do you derive `E(h(N)) = sum(i=1..N) P(ancestor(i,N))`?

Comment: @justhalf Explained, and removed the bit about binary trees: it's easier to think about the problem as permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario (which is often what is sought) is O(n). If the list is sorted in reverse order every single one will result in an assignment.

HOWEVER, if your assignment is the most expensive operation why don't you just store it's index and only ever copy once, if at all? In that case, you will have exactly 1 assignment and n-1 comparisons.