# How often does the maximum get updated?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Given the below algorithm:

```
Algorithm Find-Max(Array, size)
Max = -INFINITY
for k:= 1 to n do
    if(A[k] > Max-sf) Then
         Max-sf:=A[k]
    end if
```

The question is what is the average times is the variable max updated?

I am practicing algorithm analysis and below is my thought but I am not sure about it so I would like to ask for advice.

Let T(n) be the number of comparisons in each call on find-Max with size = n.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n
```

where 1/n is the probability such that the the largest number is at the index n. Therefore,

```
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1/(n-1)
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + 1/(n-2)
```

By telescoping,

```
T(n) = 1/n + 1/(n-1)+ 1/(n-2) + .... + 1
```

, which is harmonic series. Therefore the average times the variable Max-sf updated is log(n))

This is how i prove it.

So, I would like to ask 3 questions:
(1) Is the proof above correct?
(2) Is there a way to get precise value of the number of comparisons?
(3) Supposed that we use the divide and conquer method by using similar idea as merge sort instead of scanning an array, will the number of updates still the same?

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask this. We're coders, not mathematicians. We use math, but rarely as part of proofs. You can refer this to the Mathematics StackExchange...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075066/time-complexity-of-below-algorithm/19075448  Yes, it is O(log n)

Comment: @panoptical Thank you for your suggestion. because there are many programmers here who are very good at math too :)

Comment: @SanjeevMurty Thank you very much. I have tried searching but could not find it. Thank you gain.

Comment: Is the variable called Max or Max-sf? there may be a typo in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure regarding your proof, but I find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075886/196211) to be the most formal and convincing one.

2) The precise number of comparisons seems to be fixed. You always do n comparisons in the loop.

3) Regarding the divide and conquer option, it can't be better than the worst case number of updates (which is n), since it behaves like:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
```

Which results in T(2^n) = 2*2^n-1, which means Theta(n) complexity.

Comment: @Eval Thank you very much. For question 2, I made the typo. I meant the average number of updating instead of comparisons. I am going to explore your proof. Thank you again.