# TADM 2-45: What's the expected number of times tmp=A[i] is performed?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to solve the following exercise (2-45) from The Algorithm Design Manual:

Consider the following algorithm to find the minimum element in an array of numbers `A[0, ..., n]`. One extra variable `tmp` is allocated to hold the current min value. Start from `A[0]`, `tmp` is compared against `A[1]`, `A[2]`, ..., `A[n]` in order. When `A[i] < tmp`, `tmp = A[i]`.

What's the expected number of times that the assignment operation `tmp = A[i]` is performed?

I found [this solution](http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.45) online but couldn't understand it. The equation

```
E[n] = E[n-1] + 1/n, E[1] = 0
```

gives `0 + 1/n + 2/n + 3/n...` but I don't think that's correct. Since what's asked has things to do with not only the smallest element, but also the 2nd smallest element, the 3rd smallest etc.

Can someone explain their thoughts on this question? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time Complexity of below algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075066/time-complexity-of-below-algorithm)

Comment: Check out my answer to this very question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075066/time-complexity-of-below-algorithm/19075886#19075886

Answer (score 4):

The solution you pointed to is correct, although it is not clearly explained.

The expected number of times the assignment to tmp is made is the sum of the probabilities of making it at each element. The probability of making the assignment at element j is the probability of element Xj to be the minimum among {X1, X2, … Xj}, which by the assumption of the auther, is 1/j because there are j elements in the above set.

The expectation is them sum(1/j) ~ ln(n).

Comment: Reading @paul-hankin 's answer in another question helped me understand your answer. Thanks!